# Why do Content Providers use URI's and not databases?

Tags: android, sqlite

We could insert data into database without using the Uri. But when we are using contentResolver we need the Uri to do anything.

Like `getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);` But in Database query execution we do not need any Uri. Like `db.execSQL(String query);`. Why is this?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: vote to close, I can't find the question...

Comment: i think the question is why do we use .insert() vs execSQL.

Comment: The question is in the title, people... this shouldn't have been closed... this is a really good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think this question is about to be closed, I think what you are asking is why when you use a content resolver you have to use a CONTENT_URI, but when using a database you dont?

**[Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)**

This is because Content Resolvers provide more functionality than just a database

> Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to
>   all applications. They're the only way to share data across
>   applications; there's no common storage area that all Android packages
>   can access.
>
> Android ships with a number of content providers for common data types
>   (audio, video, images, personal contact information, and so on). You
>   can see some of them listed in the android.provider package. You can
>   query these providers for the data they contain (although, for some,
>   you must acquire the proper permission to read the data).
>
> When a query is initiated, **the Android system identifies the content
>   provider that's the target of the query and makes sure that it is up
>   and running.**

**Database**

With a database, it is not accessible from ANY application via a Content Provider (unless you write one). Using db.execSQL, you are only querying your database and not a content provider, thus you don't need to provide a CONTENT_URI. Your `db` object IS the data store.

Answer (score 1):

[Content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are much more powerful(example: can access much more than just sql) and safer than just using execSQL(example: open to sql injection attacks).

this is the cheap answer, I know I can find some documentation to support this.  I'll keep looking for a link.

Comment: all the easy questions are either closed, answered to quickly, or the questioner doesn't mark the answer.   Editing is the only way i can get points :(     I disagree with how much questions are closed but o well, guess I'm the 1%  lol.